# What cartoon or marionette show features respiring plants in a "corn" field?

Tags: story-identification

I have distinct memory of watching a show in elementary school (~1985-1988) that was either stop-motion animated or used marionettes similar to Thunderbirds. Unfortunately memory of the particulars of the show are quite vague.

Here are the elements (I think) I remember:

- A rocket lands on possibly another planet.
- There is a female crew member
- Near the rocket there is something similar to a corn field
- The plants in the field have sacs that perform animal-like respiration
- One of the astronauts enters the "corn" field to search? explore? while leaving the other two behind
- There was a shiny vertical metal ladder to reenter the rocket

This may have been an educational film since it was show in my elementary class to the whole class. The elementary was in the US.

I've looked at plot synopses for episodes of Thunderbirds and Captain Scarlet, but none seem to match my memory. Although, the synopses I've been able to find are very brief.

We didn't finish watching the show, I think class got out before it ended. I always wanted to watch the end of it.